# multipass cloud-init.yaml ssh asks for password

Tags: cloud-init, multipass

I am trying to get ssh working in multipass, so I can `ssh user@ip -i key.pub` not using multipass shell.

I am using the following cloud-init:

```
ssh-keygen -C vmadmin -f user_key

users:
  - default
  - name: vmadmin
    sudo:  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa xxx vmadmin

multipass launch -n testvm --cloud-init cloud-init.yaml
chmod 400 user_key.pub
```

Why is it asking for password, when ssh into the multipass instance?:

```
sudo ssh vmadmin@192.168.64.2 -i user_key.pub
Password:
sudo: a password is required
```

Also tried adding password to cloud-init.yaml

```
passwd: 123
```

But unable to login?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was simply that I used public key:

```
sudo ssh vmadmin@192.168.64.2 -i user_key.pub
```

It should of course be used with private key:

```
sudo ssh vmadmin@192.168.64.2 -i user_key
```